# How can I get this code (from Java tutorial on sockets) to run?

Tags: java, sockets

I've **just** started with this section of the tutorial. I only have a basic understanding of what ports are, etc.

I tried to run this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("taranis", 7);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                               + "the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

---

"Don't know about host: taranis.
Java Result: 1"

Is the error catch I get. From my limited understanding; is the echo-server something which exists on my machine? If that's the case, what do I need to do to get this running? Or am I way off?
Also why have they chosen "taranis" as a parameter?

Ive also replaced "taranis" with "localhost" to see what happened. 
It ended up catching an IOException this time.

EDIT: So I've found that the echo server is disabled by default in win7 and have activated it. However I cant even connect to it on telnet. I think I may just be in over my head. I've also tried the sockets you have recommended with no success.

Comment: Try replacing `taranis` with `localhost` or your computer's network name.

Comment: @Blender Thx, but I've already tried localhost as parameter. Trying "YOONSI-PC" which is my network name ended up with the same result as localhost.

Comment: Now I'm thinking that port 7 isn't activated by default on windows 7. So I'm trying to work out if it's actually active or not.

Comment: Try a more standard test port like `5000` or `8080`. Are you running it as Admin?

Comment: This maybe a silly question but I'm currently just playing with this snippet of code in Netbeans. How do I run it as an admin from within Netbeans? Or do I have to rather run Netbeans as an admin?

Comment: No success with other ports. I tried "telnet localhost 7" from admin cmd prompt and it will not connect. "Could not open connection to the host on port 7." Connection failed.

Comment: *"Now I'm thinking that port 7 isn't activated by default on windows 7. So I'm trying to work out if it's actually active or not."* - THAT is a question that is better asked on superuser.com or serverfault.com ... along with the obvious followup questions.

Comment: @StephenC No disrespect intended, but it was not a question. I was just trying to note what steps I'm taking to get this under wraps.

Comment: @yoonsi - People assume that comments like that are actually questions, and that the OP hasn't bothered to use a '?' character.  Non-questions should be prefixed with "Don't answer this" ... if you would prefer people not to provide you with answers :-).  And I'm just saying that if it was a question you'll get better answers somewhere else.

Comment: @StephenC My Apologies.  English is infact my second language. I just assumed that if I didn't use a question mark in the comments section it would be taken as a comment. I'll be sure to remember.

Comment: @yoonsi - You've got it the wrong way around.  The correct English usage **is** to use a question mark (like you did).  But a lot of people here are either ignorant of this or lazy, and don't use a question mark properly.  Rather than being pedantic about it, regulars like me will assume that the OP means to ask a follow-up question when a comment could reasonably be interpreted as a question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same tutorial:

> ... The Socket constructor used here requires the name of the machine and the port number to which you want to connect. The example program uses the host name taranis. This is the name of a hypothetical machine on our local network. When you type in and run this program on your machine, change the host name to the name of a machine on your network. Make sure that the name you use is the fully qualified IP name of the machine to which you want to connect. The second argument is the port number. Port number 7 is the port on which the Echo server listens.`

In any case, you will probably want to change taranis to `"localhost"` and make sure an echo service is running on your machine. If it's not, you could use something like the following code to simulate an echo server.

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new EchoServer(INSERTPORT).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int port;

    private ArrayList<Client> clientList;
    private ExecutorService clientRunner;

    public EchoServer(int port) throws IOException {
        this.port = port;
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        clientRunner = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        clientList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void sendMessageToAll(String message) {
        for (Client c : clientList) {
            c.displayMessage(message);
        }
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            clientList.add(new Client(serverSocket.accept(), this));
            clientRunner.execute(clientList.get(clientList.size()-1));
        }
    }
    private class Client implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;
        private Scanner input;
        private Formatter output;

        public Client(Socket s) throws IOException {
            clientSocket = s;

            input = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            output = new Formatter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        }

        public void displayMessage(String s) {
            output.format(s + "\n");
            output.flush();
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                if(input.hasNextLine()) {
                    sendMessageToAll(input.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Just for completeness, as you mentioned some problems running the code, you run the server (this code) and leave it running in the background, then run the client (the code you posted). I tested it, works fine.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've decided to just move on with the learning process. Your little server allowed me to do so, so that's the main thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Use the **loopback address of 127.0.0.1** instead of taranis.
2. Use **port higher than 1024**, something like 4444, 8333 etc....

I am also adding my code that i used to learn Client Server Commnu

Client Side Code:

```
public class ClientWala {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Boolean b = true;
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);

    System.out.println("connected: "+s.isConnected());


    OutputStream output = s.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(output,true);

    // to write data to server
    while(b){

        if (!b){

             System.exit(0);
        }

        else {
            pw.write(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        }
    }


    // to read data from server
    InputStream input   = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String data = null;

    while ((data = br.readLine())!=null){

        // Print it using sysout, or do whatever you want with the incoming data from server

    }




    }
}
```

Server Side Code:

```
public class ServerTest {

    ServerSocket s;

    public void go() {

        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(44457);

            while (true) {

                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class MyCon implements Runnable {

        Socket incoming;

        public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        incoming.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String inp = null;

                boolean isDone = true;

                System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
                System.out.println();
                while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                    System.out.println(inp);
                    if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                        isDone = false;
                        s.close();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ServerTest().go();

    }

}
```